# Spring boot create jar using gradle with specific spring profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have in my Spring boot project this files:

```
application.properties
application-prod.properties
```

I want to create gradle task which will output two jar files.

Both jar files should contain:

```
application.properties
application-prod.properties
```

In the first jar file, `application.properties` should contain

```
spring.profiles.active=default
```

in the second jar file, `application.properties` should contain

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Typically, you would have a single jar and define the active spring profile on execution of the spring boot app. Is there a reason you want two separate jars?

Comment: According to the [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/codebase) there should be only one binary with many deploys. Thane you can [specify a profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-set-active-spring-profiles), for example, on the command line.

Comment: @Compass In my previous company, we did this way with Ant for some not Spring projects. But if this is hard to do with spring-boot using Gradle, is there a way to define Gradle tasks which will build jar for the specific Environment. e.g. buildDev task will make dev environment jar, buildProd task will make prod environment jar. I would like to have active profile specified in a jar, not use launch arguments while starting jar etc. If I understand correctly, the only difference this jars will have is parameter "spring.profiles.active". I tried making it that way but couldn't. Thank you.